# Why this error tryng to cURL an API? OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to

Tags: ssl, certificate, curl, openssl

I am going crazy with the following problem. Some times ago I was able to retrieve data from some API using the following cURL command involving the use of an SSL certificate, but now I am obtaining the following error message:

```
andrea@ubuntu:~/Desktop/certificati/abc/abc$ sudo curl --location --cert client2.cer --key client2.key --pass "password"  --request  GET "https://myserver.myorganization.it/ws-application/service/distretti/_/_/_"  -v
[sudo] password for andrea: 
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying SERVER IP ADDRESS:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to myserver.myorganization.it (SERVER IP ADDRESS) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to myserver.myorganization.it:443 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to myserver.myorganization.it:443
```

What could be the reason\cause of this error? How can I try to debug it?

I also have the CA certificate file, can I try to verify it with my client certificate\key files?

Comment: Can you re-test with `--tls-max 1.2`? (Why are you using sudo with curl, anyway?)

Comment: Has the client certificate expired? Check with `openssl x509 -in client2.cer -text -noout`

Comment: @mtak it seems to be valid: Not After : Jul 28 10:47:46 2031 GMT

Comment: @user1686 in this way it worked fine. What is changed?